# AngularJS tutorial can't open in Chrome Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, angularjs, google-chrome

Started official [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) of AngularJS. It works fine in firefox, but can't open example and run tests on Chrome.

```
Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116
node --version v0.10.26
Mac OS X Version 10.9.2
```

Tried wget some json resource, it works.

```
wget http://localhost:8000/app/phones/phones.json 
--2014-04-20 01:14:37--  http://localhost:8000/app/phones/phones.json
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1, fe80::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8000... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6845 (6.7K) [application/json]
Saving to: 'phones.json'

100%[======================================>] 6,845       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-04-20 01:14:37 (466 MB/s) - 'phones.json' saved [6845/6845]
```

HTTP logs:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./ on port: 8000
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Sat, 19 Apr 2014 22:14:37 GMT] "GET /app/phones/phones.json" "Wget/1.15 (darwin13.0.0)"
[Sat, 19 Apr 2014 22:16:06 GMT] "GET /app/phones/phones.json" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

Same resource on Chrome:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8000
```

Empty in Chrome Console and in Network:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution for my case.

Firstly started looking for proxies. After sniffing around loopback interface with wireshark, found that localhost is linked to ::1. "::1" is 127.0.0.1 for IPv6.

Firefox is somehow resolves the problem, but Chrome not.

Simply add the line below to hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

It fixes problem.